# Read Shopify shop shipping origin

Tags: shopify

Anyone know how to read a Shopify shop's **shipping origin**? The address you can read via the Shop API appears to be just for billing.

I've tried using the 'Location' API but that seems to reference the same data as the Shop API.

Comment: How to you know the address set as the shop address in the admin settings is not the origin used for carrier shipping api calls? Can you actually set a different one somewhere proving it?

Comment: You set the shipping origin in /admin/settings/shipping - this is the address that is passed to the app webhook that returns carrier rates. Of course, we can override this at the webhook stage and choose our own origin, but I'm trying to stick to the Shopify point-of-truth

Comment: You're handed the shipping origin in the carrier shipping API payload. If you want to change it, that is where you change it.

Comment: See previous comment. There's also the 'Location' API but that just returns the standard shop address as the first item. I imagine more Locations are added with systems using the Retail POS package that have multiple stores.

Answer (score 2):

I hope it may be useful for someone.

There is a field called primary_location_id in Shop resource

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's what you are looking for but shop.address.summary liquid variable might help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Alice. I'm dealing directly with the API from by embedded app in the admin area; see https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/shop#show - Liquid variables are used in templates.